# Is it possible to generate from code using T4

Tags: t4

I have used T4 to generate partial classes from some input file (XML, etc) and then hand code additional partial bits onto those generated classes.

Is it possible to go the other way? To hand craft partial classes, and use T4 to template  boiler plate bits to them?

Obviously I can't use reflection to look for the classes since it's not compiled yet, but I see Visual Studio inspect uncompiled code for different utilities. Perhaps Visual Studio offers some feature to support this I don't know about. Long shot, I guess.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also, you can use T4 with VS's CodeModel to read the code in your project without compiling and then generate from that metadata.

There's some pointers to examples here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/garethj/archive/2009/09/25/dte-and-t4-better-together.aspx

Comment: Thanks! That link was really helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, T4 is used this way frequently. Yes, it requires reflection, but partial classes compile even if bits of them aren't generated yet. I would look at examples for generating strongly typed views as described [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdevtools/archive/2009/01/29/t4-templates-a-quick-start-guide-for-asp-net-mvc-developers.aspx) for examples of using reflection to generate new files.